# Lightweight jQuery tree controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I need a simple jQuery folder tree controller with the following features:

- to be based on a nested unordered list
- expand/collapse
- drag and drop to reorder
- ajax support (not sure if I need this)

Which is the tree controller you think is the most appropriate for this?

Thank you in advance for your time,
titel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simple tree at [SIMPLE TREE +DRAG'NDROP](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SimpleTree). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Treeview plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) is nice but doesn't have D&D re-order, but I'm pretty sure it's possible to hack something with jQuery UI dragable & dropable. (I don't understand what you mean by ajax support)

Comment: Note as of April 2010: While the plugin still works as it is, it has some shortcomings, and not maintained anymore. There are now plenty of alternative jQuery tree plugins.